# How to catch vue-router's "uncaught error during transition"?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

There's some error rasied on my page, and vue-router warning:

```
[vue-router] Uncaught error during transition:
```

I wonder how to catch it and remove this warning? From vue-router's doc, I cannot find a hook function handle errors. I also tried to catch error

```
  router.beforeEach((transition) => {
    try {
      transition.next()
    } catch (e) {
      transition.abort()
      console.log('route caught', e)
    }
  })
```

Although I can catch the error now, but the warning still raised, and I don't know if I did the right thing.

And there is another warning when error raised

```
[vue-router] transition.next() should be called only once.
```

How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a promise AND call next use either one or the other